# javascript foreach loop group by values

Tags: javascript

For example, given this array of objects:

```
[ 
    { userid: "5", articleid: "3"},
    { userid: "5", articleid: "3"},
    { userid: "5", articleid: "3"},
    { userid: "1", articleid: "2"}
]
```

I want to display the values ​​this way Without repetition inside the loop:

```
[ 
    { userid: "5", articleid: "3"},
    { userid: "1", articleid: "2"}
]
```

The code used is javascript

```
var newMessage = '';
    function realTime(){
        db.collection('chat').where('userid', '==', <?php echo $id; ?>)
        .orderBy('time')
        .onSnapshot(function(snapshot) {
            newMessage = '';
            snapshot.docChanges().forEach(function(change) {
              if (change.type === "added") {
                //console.log(change.doc.data());
                const elements = [change.doc.data()];
                console.log([...new Set(elements.map(JSON.stringify))].map(JSON.parse));
              }
            });

            if (chatHTML != newMessage) {
                $('.msg_body').append(newMessage);
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/14438954/16688813

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960473/get-all-unique-values-in-a-javascript-array-remove-duplicates

Comment: Check documentations on how array functions work, you'll be able to find the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) with [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to achieve the desired result.

```js
const arr = [
  { userid: "5", articleid: "3" },
  { userid: "5", articleid: "3" },
  { userid: "5", articleid: "3" },
  { userid: "1", articleid: "2" },
];

const set = new Set();

const result = arr.filter(({ userid, articleid }) => {
  if (set.has(`${userid}|${articleid}`)) return false;
  else {
    set.add(`${userid}|${articleid}`);
    return true;
  }
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a an easy way to do it.

```js
const elements = [ 
    { userid: "5", articleid: "3"},
    { userid: "5", articleid: "3"},
    { userid: "5", articleid: "3"},
    { userid: "1", articleid: "2"}
];
console.log([...new Set(elements.map(JSON.stringify))].map(JSON.parse));
```

Comment: Wow, this is cool.  I've never seen this before.  I will research how this works.

Comment: Thank you
I modified the question, the code used inside forEach, so it brings me the result more than once, so what is the solution?
See the question again after adding the code inside forEach

Comment: @MedhatFarid not sure what you are doing in the new code. I used console.log just to show the result..you don't need to use the console.log as such

Comment: Just use it to modify the code, the problem now is that the result is repeated

Answer (score 0):

You can use [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) on your array to do it.

The first one allows you to filter only by userID, and the second one with both values to separate also those who are not really duplicates.

```js
const values = [
  { userid: "5", articleid: "3" },
  { userid: "5", articleid: "3" },
  { userid: "5", articleid: "3" },
  { userid: "5", articleid: "2" },
  { userid: "1", articleid: "2" },
];

const first = values.filter(
  (element, index, array) =>
    array.findIndex(
      (otherElement) => element.userid === otherElement.userid
    ) === index
);

const second = values.filter(
  (element, index, array) =>
    array.findIndex(
      (otherElement) =>
        element.userid === otherElement.userid &&
        element.articleid === otherElement.articleid
    ) === index
);

console.log("first", first);
console.log("second", second);
```

By searching a little more, there was already the answer [on several posts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56757215/16261616).